How to parent Blender's native window to a top level system native window
I am a pipeline dev, I have successfully used PySide6 and python 3.11 to create a widget container of the Microsoft Windows 11 Blender 4.2.2 native window so that my child widgets can be now minimized when Blender app is being minimized as well.
I want to port this behaviour to Linux, Rocky Linux 8 more specifically, and I am using the command wmctrl -lx making the console throw up all the available open top level OS native windows together with their windows handles.
I believe I am parsing correctly this output and retrieving Ok Blender 4.2.2 window handle.
In spite of this, the container widget which holds the blender window is not being embed into my QMainWindow, instead, they show up as two separate windows. (see screenshot).
I m presuming this has something to do with gnome-desktop and the "libdecor" library, which allows to embed a toolbar for every application being launched.
My question is: how can I disable this behaviour/or find a reason why this is not working yet in Linux as it is in Windows 11.


Hello and welcome. As it stands, this question doesn't seem to be specifically about using Blender in a strick sense, and as such it is considered off topic here. Maybe a good fit for either https://unix.stackexchange.com/ , https://superuser.com/ or perhaps https://stackoverflow.com/

hi @DuarteFarrajotaRamos, i finally managed to figure it out and do it. Would it be possible to post the solution here? Due to the intricacies of Blender launched from within Blender i think the solution is very specific and useful to other users using Blender in Linux with no window decorations from the X11 windowing manager. I would rather post the solution here, rather than in those forums, as i say, it is very blender specific.

I've reopened the post for you, you are now able to answer your question
